# Complete lock-up of a Java process

Tags: java, lockup

This one is baffling. All of a sudden we've started experiencing a situation where all threads in a Java process reach a BLOCKED state and the process is completely frozen. There's no jvm.log or hs*.log file to point to what's going on.

A jstack dump lists many threads, all in BLOCKED state, some of them as baffling as this:

```
Thread 14766: (state = BLOCKED)
- java.lang.String.substring(int, int) @bci=62, line=1939 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.Formatter.parse(java.lang.String) @bci=73, line=2469 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.Formatter.format(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=213, line=2438 (Compiled frame)
- java.util.Formatter.format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=7, line=2367 (Compiled frame)
- java.lang.String.format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]) @bci=9, line=2769 (Compiled frame)
```

(cropped the rest)

Or this:

```
Thread 14794: (state = BLOCKED)
- java.lang.Throwable.toString() @bci=17, line=344 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object) @bci=10, line=2826 (Compiled frame)
- java.io.PrintWriter.println(java.lang.Object) @bci=1, line=710 (Interpreted frame)
- java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(java.io.PrintWriter) @bci=6, line=509 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(java.lang.Throwable) @bci=19, line=60 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep() @bci=50, line=87 (Interpreted frame)
- org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep() @bci=13, line=413 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=26, line=313 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=2, line=276 (Interpreted frame)
- org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=10, line=162 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=106, line=251 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=41, line=66 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=26, line=206 (Compiled frame)
- org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(java.lang.String, org.apache.log4j.Priority, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable) @bci=14, line=391 (Interpreted frame)
- org.apache.log4j.Category.error(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable) @bci=37, line=322 (Interpreted frame)
```

(cropped the rest)

I must admit that while I've tried to search for a cause online, I don't know where to begin looking for it.

This is happening under jdk1.6.0_31

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of multithreaded programming: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock

Comment: check it for deadlock in an IDE, wherein you can view each thread's execution. How many threads are running? got enough memory?

Comment: Similar situation in this log it seems: http://issues.hudson-ci.org/secure/attachment/19564/trace.log

Comment: Why would there be a deadlock in Throwable.toString() and String.substring(int,int)

Comment: @aioobe Yes that looks similar, any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are they all blocked in string operations? Have you run out of heap perm gen space maybe (do a 'jstat -gc' on the hung process)

Comment: Result of jstat:

 S0C    S1C    S0U    S1U      EC       EU        OC         OU       PC     PU    YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
40000.0 36928.0 9345.7  0.0   557952.0 518204.3 1271808.0   339799.0  145408.0 144225.6   1254   68.950  403  1281.828 1350.778

Looks like there may be an issue of perm space indeed.

Comment: However, max perm size is set to "-XX:MaxPermSize=192m". So why is only 140mb or so available?

Comment: Well it may be trying to grow it and hitting some other limit. As I understand it -Xmx (max heap size) is the max for combined young and old generations and perm gen space is in addition to that, so that should not be limiting factor. But then JVM has always seemed to behave bit strangely when perm gen fills up, so maybe try setting a fixed, larger size (-XX:PermSize=192m). Could also try turning on perm gen collecting using CMS collector.

Comment: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled

Comment: are you running on 32bit OS? could be the 3GB process VM limit

Comment: It's a 64-bit OS. Why would there be a need to set the PermSize if the MaxSize is already set to 192?

Comment: I don't know - but I have seen strange behaviour with perm gen when it fills up so I think it might be worth a go

Comment: You can see this here:

  PGCMN      PGCMX       PGC         PC      YGC   FGC    FGCT     GCT
   22528.0   196608.0   131072.0   131072.0   426   263  741.838  754.752

Comment: This is what we're getting from with the gcutil option, looks like it's a garbage collection (Eden space) that's locking it all down:

  S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT
  0.00   0.00 100.00  96.82  99.98    426   12.914   297  877.414  890.328

Comment: Apparently the issue was that Eden was filling up quickly and the GC kept running endlessly because of a loop that was generating Strings like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

What is the OS? Multithreading issues are many times OS dependent since their implementation is OS specific. Java threads are just an abstraction of OS threading.

/Koya

Comment: Couldn't figure how to add a comment. Thanks for saying it aloud.

Answer (score 0):

I would run the program with `-verbosegc`. It appears to be blocked waiting for some free space.

Answer (score 0):

This part of exception:

```
org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent) @bci=26, line=206 (Compiled frame)
org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(java.lang.String, org.apache.log4j.Priority, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable) @bci=14, line=391 (Interpreted frame)
org.apache.log4j.Category.error(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Throwable) @bci=37, line=322 (Interpreted frame)
```

Probably, it is related to a bug in log4j. Have a look at the following webpage:

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41214